# How do I conditionally control the visibility of a control in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I've got an asp:Image. I want this control to display, only if `<%#Eval("Image")%>` is not `null`.

I do not know how to write this conditional statement. What I'm trying to say is something like this (if the value of 'image' taken from the data structure is not null, then display the image. Otherwise, do not):

```
<%#Eval("Image")%> != 0 ? <asp:Image ID="image" runat="server"/>
```

I'm aware that this is not the syntax - consider it as pseudocode, as I have never had to write a conditional statement in the markup.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can bind the `Visible` property of your control to the expression and call `DataBind()` while the page is loading:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" id="image" Visible='<%#Eval("Image") != null %>' />
```

If you are not using server controls and want to show/hide simple markup, you can simply enclose it in an `if` statement:

```
<% if ( condition ) { %>
    <img src='<%= linkToImageSource %>' />
<% } %>
```

Comment: @Mehrad Afshari Do you think you could suggest something else, as the image is still displayed even with the condition?

Comment: @Sean Are you calling `DataBind` during page load? Are you sure the expression `Eval("Image")` is null? I'm sure the method works in general.

Comment: Eval("Image") does not return null actually. It's just blank. However when comaring to " " it still did not work

Comment: I managed to solve it by just accessing the repeater from the code-behind and checkign from there! Other users might find your suggestion helpful so I'll accept it :)