# How to show\hide a table row dynamically inside another user control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ascx

I have two user controls inside one page.

In the first one there are controls of combo-box for filtering the data, and in the second one there is another user control that depends on the selected value in the combo-box.

In the second user control I have a table and in one of the rows I added another user control.

I need to show\hide that user control (the third one) by specific value choosen in the first user control.

I'v choose to do so by show\hide the row in the table by set style:display that depends on function in code behind.

I'v tried many different ways to do so, but none of them work.

My code:

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
 <table id="Table1" style="margin-left: 25px; font-size: 12px">
     <tr style="display:<%=SetUcDisplay("some value") %>">
         <td colspan="3" id="td1">
             <userControl:control ID="ThirdUserControl" runat="server" />
  </td>
            </tr>
```

SetUcDisplay:

```html
protected string SetUcDisplay(string value) {
   if (value == "never mind") {
       return "block";
   } else {
       return "none";
   }
}
```

So it doesn't failed but also not showing the user control.
I think maybe I should do a refresh to the Second user control but how?

Any other suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Set the visibility directly to the control: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115872/how-do-i-conditionally-control-the-visibility-of-a-control-in-asp-net

Comment: its not working...

Comment: Changing the UpdateMode to "Always" solved my problem