# How can i use If condition in aspx page for image url?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My `dataset` return this table [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEM9N.png).How can i use `If else` conditons in `aspx` page?I want if the `File_path` is `Null` or `empty` then image not show because if `File_Path` is empty then it give me error,I want if `File_Path` is not empty then image will be show.Following error

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Here is my code

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" RepeatLayout="Table">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="<%#GetStyleForMsgList(Eval("MsgSender").ToString()) %>  MainChatListClass">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetPerfactName(Eval("MsgSender").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ChatMsg") %>'></asp:Label>
             <asp:Label ID="lblfile" runat="server" Visible ="false"  Text='<%# Eval("File_Path") %>'></asp:Label>
           <% if (Eval("File_Path") != null)
              {%>
            <asp:Image ID ="img" runat ="server" ImageUrl ='<%# Eval("File_Path") %>' />
            <% } %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: What error do you get when `File_Path` is null?

Comment: i already tell this error `Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.`

Comment: I just want if `File_Path` is null then it never go to `asp:Image` tag if `File_Path` have some value then `asp:image` use

Comment: You can't use `Eval` this way. What you can do is make image visible or invisible based on File_Path value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115872/how-do-i-conditionally-control-the-visibility-of-a-control-in-asp-net

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i can make image visible or invisible but issue is when `File_Path` is `null` it shows error.

Comment: Did you follow the SO link which I shared.

Comment: I am looking and trying this,

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanksssssssssssssssssss alot,,visible working

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya but how can i set width and height of image if image is visible,i set height and width of image but it shows blank area when image path is null